# How to prevent users from affecting number of button clicked times

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, onclicklistener

I have a game written in JavaScript and what it basically does is start a ten seconds timer and register the number of times the user is able to click on a certain button, before the timer elapses.

**How the code works:**

When a user clicks on the button, an element gets added to an array, using `push` function, then a different function returns the length of the array as the number of times clicked.

**The problem with this:**

If a user opens up the dev tools and alters the number of times an element is added to the array per click, this will change the outcome of the result.

**My Approach:**

What I decided to do is to store the length before I ran the `push` function and also after I ran the `push` function, then compare their differences and if it's greater than `1`, it means something is not right. This seemed to work in my head until I wrote it down in code and discovered that if the user pushed multiple times before I checked the differences then it would go unnoticed. Please big brained guys, help me.

**My code:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn.z', function () {
        // start listening

        startCountingClicks()
    })

    var timerStarted = false;
    var tc = [];

    function startCountingClicks () {



            $('.btn.z').html('ClickZed');
            $('.Score').html('Your Score: '+gettc()+" clicks");
            if (timerStarted == false) {
                startTimer(10, $('#time'));
            }

            // user does multiple push before this function: startCountingClicks is called

            var previous_length = tc.length; // get length before push
            tc.push(1);
            var new_length = tc.length; // get length after push

            if (new_length - previous_length !== 1) {
                console.log("fraud"); // this is supposed to catch a thief!!!
            }
            console.log(new_length+" "+previous_length);

            timerStarted = true;

    }

    function gettc (){
        // get number of clicks
        return tc.length ;
    }
```

**A code that totally breaks this:**

```
$('button').click(function(){tc.push(1); tc.push(1)})
```

**EDIT:**

I do not wish to protect against dev tools, though I am not against that method if it works. I just wish to get a better way of counting my clicks, a way that can't be affected by writing code on the dev tools.

Comment: Why do you want to protect against dev tools. Those tools do what it hints at: develop code. It is normal that with these tools you can invalidate all script and put something else instead. Use server sided code to do real validation.

Comment: I do not wish to protect against dev tools, I wish to not rely on them not breaking my code

Comment: That is what I mean. Someone could write `console.log('you won! You clicked 1000000 times in 10 seconds. You are AMAZING')`. What is the fun in that?

Comment: You cant really protect your code client-side. A skilled user will always be able to meddle with it - you can only give them challanges while doing so. To truly protect your game you would need to validate it on the server itself.

Comment: how can I perform a server side validation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really stop people from doing stuff on the client side. It is pointless trying to prevent that. The best thing you can do is make sure whatever is sent matches what you expect on the server side.

Comment: I don't know what to expect, users click on the button as fast as they can, so they'll win and I can't tell when a user is cheating or not.

Comment: There is no way to check it sadly. Unless you actually send the click event to your server and count them and send back a response... but even then I can spam your server with click events because I can replicate it... there is no way you can authenticate clicks only sadly. You will need to think of other ways to perhaps making your game more fair if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Your best bet is to make it secure by obscurity. So do stuff like minify your js code, or something like that.

Comment: Done that obscurity thingy already. I guess I'll have to do as you've said. Thanks.

Comment: What tools do you suggest I use for the obscurity, I currently use https://javascriptobfuscator.com @Chris

Comment: Sorry I can't help you there, I normally do that myself.